# asp.net web forms constructor?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to load a dictionary with some data and use it in the button event handler of a web form. Where is the appropriate place to put this code? There is a Page_Load method, but I don't want it to run every time the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a Page Load event handler, call the method only once when the page first loads.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
        // your code to load dictionary here, or a method call.
    }
}
```